# What is the best approach to manage my list permission

Tags: permissions

I have the following:-

1. Site collection.
2. A list inside the site collection, where I have inherited the permission for the list from the site collection. Which include having the build-in groups; visitors, members, owner, excel viewer.

Now I need to include users who are visitors in the site collection to have Edit permission on the list. So which approach I should follow. I tried to stop the permission inheritance , and I modified the four groups users, but adding or removing users from the groups will affect the site collection also. As it seems that they will be using the same groups. So which approach I should follow?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the permissions inheritance on the list and update the visitors group to have Contribute permissions on the  list. This will trickle down to all the files giving them the ability to edit the files.

If your concern is that these are in fact 2 different groups, then you'll need to create another group at the root of the site collection with only the desired users. Break the permissions inheritance on the list and delete the user groups except for the owners. Add the new group with the desired permissions. This way you can maintain 2 different groups and give the appropriate (sub)set access.

Comment: but i am afraid that stopping the inheritance and deleting the current groups, will cause the groups to be deleted from the site collection also. as when i stop inheritance and add new users to the groups at the list level, those users will be added on the site collection level also. so i got confused ..

Comment: @johnG when you delete a group from a list, or any other securable item, for which you have broken inheritance you are just removing the group from the list, not actually deleting it.

Comment: ok i see, but i am unable to remove the group. when i go to the list permission ,and  if i select a group there is no option or button to remove the group ?

Comment: Select the checkbox near the group name, then click on Remove user permissions

Comment: so the best approach is to stop the inheritance inside the list, remove all the groups inside the list except the owner. add new group named ListMemebers with edit permission . what do u think ?

Comment: @johnG yes, that's what you should do. Also, as it is basically what PirateEric explained, please mark his answer as accepted.

Comment: but now i deleted all the groups on the list , after i stopped the inheritance . then i went to my site setting and i added a new group . but this group will be added inside all the lists under the site collection. so i have to modify the permission for the newly added group on each list. so is there a better way to manage this. i am thinking of giving the newly added group View-Only permission on the site, and then modify the permission for the group on the list to have Edit ? what do u think ?

Comment: That works too. The general idea is to create all the groups you may need first so all lists and libraries inheriting permissions pick up these groups, then break permission inheritance on the lists where needed and remove all unnecessary groups. Otherwise you just create more work for yourself having to add the groups.